# smooth curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

how do I show that $x^2-y^2= 0$ is NOT smooth in any neighbourhood of the the point $(0,0)$? I just thought of taking the gradient and showing it is zero at the origin. But I'm not sure if that's the way to do it.

Comment: That's not good enough. For example the equation $x^2=0$ defines a smooth curve even when its gradient is zero at the origin.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the set? This equation is equivalent to $y = \pm x$.

Comment: @nik Thank you for your comment.